# Layout bug with election

Tags: bug, design

I noticed a layout bug on the election screen. My choices overlap the edge of the text and blue background with the profile information.

[image: screen shot showing the problem]

As you can see the "a" is clipped by my second choice and my third choice slightly overlaps the blue background with the profile information.

I'm using Firefox 51.0.1 on a Windows 10 machine.

Comment: You know SE has a memory leak in FF.  FF is the worst browser to use with SE.

Comment: @blankip I didn't know that. FF has enough market share that you would think a company that built its business around performance would plug a memory leak. Besides I don't think a memory leak would affect the layout.

Comment: It doesn't effect layout but if you leave a tab active it will chew up your memory.